# Using the forms authentication tables in ASP Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a database which is created using Forms authentication in asp.net but now i want to develop an other application which uses the same user names and passwords and should be able to login to the new App which is developed using MVC 5 Aspnet Identity. So i want to be able to authenticate the user in the new App using their old creds.

My old database structure

[image]

I know that Asp Identity Individual Authentication mode will generate other set of tables i would also like to stop this default behavior as i don't want Iddentity tables created in the old Db.

PLease guide me how could i achieve this. Thanks

Comment: What about using a STS? i think it's supported by ASP.NET Identity, didn't have the time to take a closer look.

Comment: Never heard of it . I will have a look

Comment: A STS acts as an Authentication Authority, which can do the authentication for all applications, provided they have setup the necessary infrastructure.
This means that your apps do not have to bother about authenticating users anymore, which will be accomplished by the STS for all apps. But you still have to do authorization of course. Perhaps it would be interesting for future apps you build.

Comment: Thanks mate that is one exciting thing to hear about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After the things i have tried. i have got it working.

1) Install the nuget package for web providers

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core
```

2) Cop these web config sections and add them in web config under  Section

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

3) Point your default connectionString towards the existing DB which consists users or you can add new connection string and use that name in the above web config sections replacing "DefaultConnection" with "newConnection"

Now you are good to go.

Just verify the Validity of the user by    `Membership.ValidateUser("username","password")`

Answer (score 0):

Web Forms and MVC both use ASP.NET Membership by default.  If your old application uses a membership provider it should be fairly easy to adapt it to MVC.  If not, you have the option of either creating a new membership provider that uses your existing database or replacing the authentication mechanisms of the MVC application.

I recommend this as a starting point for your research:  http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way

Alternatively, there are a variety of ways you could migrate user accounts from the old application to the new MVC application.  If backward-compatibility with the old application is not necessary, this may be your best (simplest) option.

Comment: The old application is created using  DefaultMembershipProvider but when i am validating the user with the user name and password for the user that i have created in my old asp Forms app i am not able to validate the user in my new App using Membership,ValidateUser('email',"password")